# Make neocomplete work like AutoComplPop

Tags: vim, neocomplete

After getting many crashes with AutoComplPop, I switched to neocomplete.  I have already found the `let g:neocomplete#enable_auto_select = 1` option which selects neocomplete's first suggestion when you hit return, as AutoComplPop does.

But I can't figure out how to do the following:

1. Let's say I want to select the 3rd suggestion, so I `<C-n>` twice to get it highlighted.  With AutoComplPop, I could now hit return and the currently highlight suggestion would be selected, and the suggestion window closed, without inserting a newline.  With neocomplete, a newline is inserted.  I realize I can just hit space and keep typing, but I want the `<CR>` behavior to be consistent whether I'm selecting the first suggestion or another.  Otherwise muscle memory leads to mistakes.
2. How can I get suggestions from all buffers, rather than just the current one?
3. Can I use neocomplete with intelli-sense plugins like vim-ruby, so that the completions for, say, a `String` object show only string methods?
4. I'd like each completion to be added as a separate entry in the undo history, so that I can `u` to undo a completion.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want for question #1 is this:

```
function! s:close_popup_and_complete()
  return pumvisible() ? neocomplete#close_popup() : "\<CR>"
endfunction

" <CR>: close popup and save indent.
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>close_popup_and_complete()<CR>
```

For question #2 I believe that behavior was a bug and has since been fixed.